# Query (complicated) or just store in another column?

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to "build" a users' models' likes. For example, if someone liked a users' thread, reply, post, then I could grab how many users liked that users "post" occurences within the application.

Currently, my favorite model takes into account the authenticated users who did the liking.

Would it be easier for me to just add the liked_id to represent the liked user?

I feel like a query would be a little troublesome. What is best practice? Would there be anything wrong with me just adding a liked_id? Would it be just another way to achieve the same thing?

Comment: You need to study on database relations. Also check the Laravel documenting about Eloquent and the different relation types. There are examples in there that are a bit like your case. And it shows that it is not difficult to create queries.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should read about [Eloquent relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships), but in general you should make your models as below:

Like Model:

```
public function post(){
   $this->belongsTo('Post','post_id');
}
```

Post Model:

```
public function likes(){
   $this->hasMany('Like','post_id');
}
```

Then you can use it:

```
$posts = Post::with('likes')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

So this is what I have come up with (on the User Model)

```
public function liked()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Thread::class)->whereHas('favorites', function ($q) { $q->where('threads.user_id', $this->id); });
    }
```

However this covers on the threads. If I want to cover the replies, various other types of comments, it seems an individual query on each of these "tables" would be necessary.

I'm not sure I want to pursue this route, as it would be tons of queries to get the number of likes the user likes... I think a column would work better.

EDIT: Nevermind, this is not really functional